# What are Epics in regard of features and backlog items in Team Foundation?

Tags: tfs, agile, azure-devops, scrum

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698363/difference-between-product-backlog-item-and-feature-in-team-foundation-work-item/19848968#19848968) I assert that a feature is a set of backlog items, but what is an epic supposed to be?

Comment: It's just a virtual package which allow you to group *Feature* items, like other *Portfolio Management* levels like *Feature* itself. It's just named as *Epic* as a higher level of *Feature*. In [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306083.aspx), *Epic* is the same as *Initiatives*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about project management term definition, not about programming.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The general consensus is that:

- ***Product backlog Item*** is something that can be delivered in a single sprint.
- ***Feature*** is something that can't be delivered in a single sprint, but that can be delivered in a single release.
- ***Epic*** is something that transcends releases.
- ***Theme*** is a cross cutting concern.

*Theme* is generally implemented as a tag in TFS and VSTS.

This is a practice that is in line with Scrum Framework, Nexus Framework, and SAfE methodology.

Answer (score 11):

From this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/05/15/scaled-agile-framework-visual-studio-online-process-template-updates/):

"Epics are hierarchically above Features. Features are mapped to Epics, like Backlog items are mapped to Features"