# Grouping in Kanban Board TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, kanban

I have user stories on my User Story board. Can I group them by Feature? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can add tag for the User Story, then set the tag colour to emphasize selected tags.

[image]

Another way is to [add swimlanes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/kanban/expedite-work). When you add swimlanes, you can visualize the status of work that supports different service-level classes. You can create a swimlane to represent any other dimension that supports your tracking needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2015, you should be able to group your User Stories underneath Epics. 
If you are not sure how Epics, features, user stories and PBIs relate to each other, I found this helpful:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30579669/9046539 
>   The general consensus is that:
>   Product backlog Item is something that can be delivered in a single sprint.
>   Feature is something that can't be delivered in a single sprint, but that can be delivered in a single release.
>   Epic is something that transcends releases.
>   Theme is a cross cutting concern.
>   Theme is generally implemented as a tag in TFS and VSTS.